# Google Play Games: tokenResponse includes access token, but no idToken

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm currently working with Google's Games API. The client sends through a user's authorization code, alongside their GPlay ID.

I'm sending this off to validate with Google, with;

```
var tokenResponse =
  new GoogleAuthorizationCodeTokenRequest(
    new NetHttpTransport(),
    JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
    "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token",
    client_id,
    client_secret,
    idTokenString,
    "")
    .execute()
```

Where the client_id and client_secret are retrieved from our client_secret as retrieved from Google, and the idTokenString is the authorization code as provided by the user logging in to the client (format: 4/xxxxx..).

After retrieving the tokenResponse, the following will return the access token without issue;

```
var accessToken = tokenResponse.getAccessToken()
```

However, the idToken as retrieved from:

```
var idToken = tokenResponse.getIdToken()
```

returns with null. As such, attempting to get the user's data to validate they're the legitimate owner of the account with;

```
var idToken = tokenResponse.parseIdToken()
```

will return a nullpointer exception.

From googling on the topic, some users seem to think that the parseIdToken method is no longer in use, and that only the accessToken can be used to retrieve such information.

However, any solutions I've found have all required use of the getIdToken, which is also returning with null.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I may be doing wrong here, or if there's another expected method for retrieving the user's details after login?

Answer (score 0):

It might be because [getIdToken()](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/reference/1.20.0/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleTokenResponse#getIdToken()) is in BETA.

As stated in the documentation - [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/):

> Features marked with @Beta at the class or method level are subject to change. They might be modified or removed in any major release. Do not use beta features if your code is a library itself (that is, if your code is used on the CLASSPATH of users outside your control).

You might want to use getIdToken from [GoogleSignInAccount](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInAccount) as a workaround.

You can check the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/release-notes) for any update.
Hope this helps.